# How can I pass reactive value into DiagrammeR::grViz()?

Tags: r, flowchart, diagrammer

I am trying to pass two reactive values into my Diagrammer::grViz code like
`[1]: paste0("Count is : \n", df()$count[rownum()])`
where df() is my dataframe and rownum() is a specific selected row number.

I am getting error like 'df() not found' or 'rownum() not found'. I suppose that this error is coming because the whole grViz code inside the inverted commas.

Also `\n` is not working inside `paste0()`.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Example code below :

```
library(shiny)

app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    
    DT::dataTableOutput("mydatatable")
  ),
  
  
  server =  shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
    mycars <- reactive({ head(mtcars)})
    output$mydatatable = DT::renderDataTable(mycars(), selection = 'single',  
                                             rownames = FALSE, options = list(dom = 't'))
    selected_row <- reactiveVal(value = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$mydatatable_rows_selected,{
      selected_row(input$mydatatable_rows_selected)
    })
    
    observeEvent(selected_row(),
                 {
                   showModal(modalDialog(
                     title = "You have selected a row!",
                     DiagrammeR::grViz("
                                       digraph flowchart {
                                       graph [layout = dot]
                                       node [shape = rectangle, width = 3, fillcolor = Biege]
                                       a [label = '@@1']
                                       b [label = '@@2']
                                       
                                       a -> b
                                       }
                                       [1]: paste0('mpg = \n', mycars()$mpg[selected_row()])
                                       [2]: paste0('cyl = \n', mycars()$cyl[selected_row()])
                                       ", width = 200)
                   ))
                 })
  })
)

app
```

Comment: Please check the updated version of question.

Comment: Thanks. While running the code I get the error `Error in parse: <text>:1:8: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING1: paste0('mpg = ..` . Do you also get the same error and that is what you want to correct?

Comment: Yes same error coming for me. If you store head(mtcars) in environment and specify selected_row as 1 then this error wouldn't come. But I want to pass reactive values.